# Debugging a SQL server trigger from a VB .NET unit test

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, debugging, triggers, integration-testing

I have a VB.NET unit test connecting to my local SQL server instance (using NHibernate). The unit test (actually more of an integration test) indirectly fires an "after insert" trigger and I'd like to **debug it**.

But my breakpoint in the trigger is being **ignored** :-(

(The icon says "Unable to bind SQL breakpoint at this time. Object containing the breakpoint not loaded.")

I have:

- enabled **SQL server debugging** in the unit test project.
- enabled **allow SQL/CLR debugging** on the instance in "SQL Server Object Explorer", although it should not matter since my trigger is a TSQL trigger.
- enabled **TCP/IP** in SQL Server Network Configuration

The unit test connects to the instance using a fairly standard connection string:
"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;"

I'm starting to wonder if what I'm trying to do is *at all possible*... (*maybe the database connection has to be created by VS itself ?*)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I just found a **workaround**. I was setting the breakpoint from the trigger view in SQL Server Object Explorer, but this doesn't work. The workaround is:

- create a new query (from SQL Server Object Explorer) that fires the trigger.
- debug that query (alt-F5), and use F11 to step through the query and the trigger(s) it fires, until a **new view** with the trigger opens.
- stop debugging, but keep the new trigger view open
- set a breakpoint in the view
- debug the unit test: At least, it breaks!

The new trigger view is called "Preview of whateverTrigger.sql". The view I used to open via SQL server object explorer is just called "whateverTrigger.sql". It's not the same view, but its breakpoints work!

I leave the question open because I'm still not understanding *why* it works this way...

Comment: Start with the obvious things: is SQL Server debugging enabled in the project's debug settings?

Comment: Yes it is, at least in the VB unit test project.